# Grok filter and logstash configuration

Tags: filter, logstash, kibana, grok

Есть журнал 2-х видов:

```
1.sshd: d.kuprevich@pts/0/79512/1012 124.25 111.561
2.74.205.155.180: 52472-76.121.32.65: 443/0/0 1.4234 11.4315
```

В первом случае после sshd: пробел

Вот конфигурация с https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/ для первого и второго случая.

```
1. (? <IP, порт>% {IPORHOST}% {NOTSPACE} \ s +% {NOTSPACE}) \ s +% {NOTSPACE: полученный_трафик} \ s +% {NOTSPACE: переданный_трафик}
2. (? <IP, порт>% {IPORHOST}% {NOTSPACE}% {NOTSPACE}) \ s +% {NOTSPACE: полученный_трафик} \ s +% {NOTSPACE: переданный_трафик}
```

Они работают каждый для своего случая, но мне нужен универсальный для обоих случаев, но я пока что-то не могу придумать. Помогите пожалуйста.

И второй вопрос, если можно, в конфиге logstash есть входной файл, в нем условно 5 строк, после вывода на консоль кибана я вижу все те же данные 2 раза, но с разными идентификаторами, подскажите пожалуйста как избавиться от дублирования дано. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Здравствуйте, Вам еще актуально?

Comment: @АртемЧернышев да, если можно уточните про повторение данных, я нашел способ избавиться от дубля(с помощью fingerprint), но не конца понял как оно работает)

Comment: Если честно не особо понятно, что вы хотите сделать, какую информацию Вы хотите парсить?

Comment: @АртемЧернышев с гроком я разобрался, как убрать дубли событий в логсташе?

Comment: со своим опытом могу сказать, что никак. Попробуйте обратиться на форум разработчика https://discuss.elastic.co/c/in-your-native-tongue/russian/15